# How to order JSON column numbers in a specific way in Java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have developed an app in Spring Boot.  The user can upload a CSV file, which contains number and code columns. In Java code, I'm able to get the number column.

CSV.File

```
number   code
12
121
122
123
1211
1212
1231
124
```

My goal and response will give:

response - goal

```
json: [{ number: 12, 
    child: [{number: 121, 
       child: [{number: 1211 }, { number: 1212 }]
    }] 
}, {number: 122 },
   {number: 123, child:[{number: 1231}] }.....etc
]
```

How do I order this JSON structure in Java by parent and child?  E.g.  12 is the parent of 121, and 121 is the parent of 1211 and 1212.

**Update:**

Input values:

```
12
121
122
123
1211
1212
1231
14
141
142
1411
25
251
2511
2512
252
253
```

response Output

```
    response: [
   {
      "number": 12,
      "child": [
         {
            "number": 121,
            "child": [
               {
                  "number": 1211
               },
               {
                  "number": 1212
               }
            ]
         },
         [
            {
               "number": 122
            }
         ],
         [
            {
               "number": 123,
               "child": [
                  {
                     "number": 1231
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "number": 14,
      "child": [
         {
            "number": 141,
            "child": [
               {
                  "number": 1411
               }
            ]
         },
         [
            {
               "number": 142
            }
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "number": 25,
      "child": [
         {
            "number": 251,
            "child": [
               {
                  "number": 2511
               },
               {
                  "number": 2512
               }
            ]
         },
         [
            {
               "number": 252
            }
         ],
         [
            {
               "number": 253
            }
         ]
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: I don't understand how you create your output. Can you explain?

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer, thanks for replay, my output as json, creating json and put the values, before that i need to find sorting parent and child from numbers,

Comment: I've edited your post to hopefully clarify what you meant.  Let me know if it's inappropriate.

Comment: I'm not really sure how this `JSON` response looks like. Parents map looks like: `{12=[121, 122, 123, 124], 121=[1211, 1212], 122=[], 123=[1231], 124=[], 1211=[], 1212=[], 1231=[]}`. If `121` is in `child` array of `12`, so why `122` is not but exists on the same level as `12`. From other side why `121` does not appear on the same level as `12`?

Comment: @MichałZiober, thanks for replay, yes i need this type: `{12=[121, 122, 123, 124], 121=[1211, 1212], 122=[], 123=[1231], 124=[], 1211=[], 1212=[], 1231=[]}`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really Java or JSON question. Your question in a nutshell is - how to assemble list of values into a tree structure knowing an ancestor-descendant relationships between elements of the list.

The algorithm I came up with is this:

1. Pick an element and check if it is a descendant of one of the roots.
   If it is not - add it to the list of roots. Check if any existing
   roots are actually descendants of this element and assign them as
   such if they are (e.g. if we have 12 in the input and then 1 we
   should move 12 to be child of 1 - though this might not exactly be
   necessary in this specific case if our input is sorted, e.g. 1 will
   always come before 12 before 123 etc). Note this part is optional due to sorting of input, but somewhat incomplete if you work with non-sorted input (will not produce proper result if wee have 12 followed by 1234 and then by 123 - both 1234 and 123 will be children of 12, but that's not correct - 1234 should become child of 123, not 12 directly). This will be a homework for you to complete it ;-)
2. If it is a descendant of some
   root - find the child of the root it may also be a descendant of. If
   there isn't such - assign it as a direct child. If there is one,
   treat that as potential parent, but then also check it's children
   for potential parent, and so on recursively.

Here's a complete working solution that produces JSON as you expected:

```
package tmpjavaproj;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

public class Test {

    public static class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
        public int number;
        public List<Node> child; // Although this should actually be called children, not child

        public int hashCode() {
            return number;
        }

        public boolean equals(Node node) {
            return number == node.number;
        }

        public int compareTo(Node node) {
            return number - node.number;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] inputs = { "12", "121", "122", "123", "1211", "1212", "1231", "14", "141", "142", "1411", "25", "251", "2511", "2512", "252", "253" };

        Set<Node> roots = new TreeSet<>();

        for (String input : inputs) {
            Node node = new Node();
            node.number = Integer.parseInt(input);

            Node root = null;
            for (Node rootCandidate : roots) {
                if (input.startsWith(String.valueOf(rootCandidate.number))) {
                    root = rootCandidate;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (root == null) {
                List<Node> rootsToChildren = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Node aRoot : roots) {
                    if (String.valueOf(aRoot.number).startsWith(String.valueOf(node.number))) {
                        rootsToChildren.add(aRoot);
                    }
                }
                if (!rootsToChildren.isEmpty()) {
                    node.child = rootsToChildren;
                    roots.removeAll(rootsToChildren);
                }
                roots.add(node);
            } else {
                Node parentCandidate = root;
                while (root != null) {
                    root = null;
                    if (parentCandidate.child != null) {
                        for (Node child : parentCandidate.child) {
                            if (input.startsWith(String.valueOf(child.number))) {
                                parentCandidate = child;
                                root = child;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (parentCandidate.child == null) {
                    parentCandidate.child = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                parentCandidate.child.add(node);
            }
        }

        Map<String, Set<Node>> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("response", roots);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(response));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a response object which has two fields.

```
public class Response() {

  public int number;

  public List<Response> children;

}
```

This class will give you what you want.

Comment: how to sorting input numbers?